# Image processing by checking object of one image of a letter occurs in another handwritten text image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I have a set of images that represent a character (letter 'O') handwritten in different ways. I want to match that with an image of handwritten text and draw a box around it. I came across using the `Template matching algorithm`, but that is not giving the output I expected. I have been trying various feature matching algorithms, and I am fairly new to Image Processing. I am doing this with `OpenCV 3.4.9` and `Java` where I'm testing it on desktop and I later want to convert it into an app. Here is what is happening with 1 image of the letter 'O' and the sample handwritten text.:

EDIT: Had to repost the question, as my previous question was cancelled due to incorrect phrasing of question

[The letter 'O'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry6Mv.png) image that is handwritten that is needed for matching.

[The handwritten text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRt7s.jpg) image that is the letter 'O' needs to be matched with.

[The output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsXVl.jpg) where the box is drawn at the incorrect place in the image.

[The expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDz45.jpg) that I am supposed to get.

The code I have is as follows (based on article I found a while back):

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class TemplateMatch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat source=null;
    Mat template=null;
    String filePath="./pics/";
    //Load image file
    source=Imgcodecs.imread(filePath+"HandText.jpg");
    template=Imgcodecs.imread(filePath+"o.png");

    Mat outputImage=new Mat();    
    int machMethod=Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;
    //Template matching method
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, template, outputImage, machMethod);


    MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(outputImage);
    Point matchLoc=mmr.maxLoc;
    //Draw rectangle on result image
    Imgproc.rectangle(source, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + template.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + template.rows()), new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    Imgcodecs.imwrite(filePath+"output.jpg", source);
    System.out.println("Completed.");
   }

}
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated as to which I can move forward to achieve this.